# Log errors from an exe invoked using createprocess function

Tags: c++, windows-console

I am trying to launch the FTPS exe through createprocess function. This FTPS exe does the following:
Connects to the server using username and password I pass as arguments
Then tries to cd to the output directory and put my file in that directory.

FYI, I am passing a script file in the command arguments. cd and put commands are composed in the script file.

Once I passed wrong filename. In the console, it says "File Not found", but I am not able to log this in my code. Is there any way to fetch these errors from the console?
As in this case, even though no FTP happened, createprocess was successful.

Comment: Please add some code, specifically the script file, it might help people answer your question.

Comment: These would be the content of the script file: cd "destination_location"
put "filename".  Sorry, I can not share the code as this is a bank's application. I am not concerned about the errors. I am able to trace the errors. I just don't know the way to log errors from console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(VS.85).aspx) sample from MSDN. It says -

> The example in this topic demonstrates how to create a child process
>   using the CreateProcess function from a console process. It also
>   demonstrates a technique for using anonymous pipes to redirect the
>   child process's standard input and output handles. Note that named
>   pipes can also be used to redirect process I/O.

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful :)